# What does an oscilloscope's input resistor and capacitor do?

Tags: oscilloscope

I watched a YouTube video on how to use an oscilloscope, *[How to Use an Oscilloscope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4zyptPLlJI)*.
[image: screenshot of Youtube]

It says there are 16 pF of capacitance and a 1 Mohm resistor connected in parallel on each input port of the oscilloscope. However, I still don't understand why there's a capacitor and resistor inside, and what the purpose of those things are.

Why are those things in there on the input port? What do they do?

Comment: It's best if you screenshot the part you want to ask

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input impedance of oscilloscopes is limited for a special reason, to accommodate wide range of input signals. In general, input sensitivity (voltage range) is limited to 5-10 V. In today's electronics it is plenty, but in the past people were working on vacuum tube amplifiers with 100 - 200 - 600 V signals. So there must be probes attenuating the signal by 10X - 100X. This was done in so-called "passive probes", which are voltage dividers.

Therefore, to get a divider, you need to have a limited input impedance, so 1 Mohm  was a reasonable value, and for a 10X attenuation the probe resistor must be big 9 Mohms. For user convenience, there is a 1-meter long cable as well. All these necessary components have parasitic capacitances, as well described in this [nice article](http://maladiets.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-design-oscilloscope-passive-probe-02.html), and the picture within:

[image]

So, 9 Mohm:1 Mohm resistors provide a 10:1 voltage divider, for DC signals. However, for AC signals the parasitic capacitance of probe head leads to effectively lower impedance than 9 Mohm, which must be compensated to maintain the same attenuation for high-frequency signals and keep the real shape of AC signals. And it should be done for a wide range of frequencies. This is done by ADDING some input capacitance, so the divider is "frequency agnostic".

As a matter of fact, this capacitance is not universal, and is individual for each manufacturer and even scope model. As result, passive 10X probes are not completely interchangeable, and their AC compensation may fail. I've seen 8 pF, 10 pF, and 13 pF inputs on various scopes.

In summary, the input impedance values of oscilloscopes are designed to accommodate frequency-compensated 1:10/1:100 probes.

Comment: A good addition to go with AC coupling component: peak voltage derating with increased frequency in passive probes.

Answer (score 12):

It would be really nice if a scope input had infinite resistance and zero capacitance but that, unfortunately is impossible. Sensitive input amplifiers will always have a small amount of input capacitance and, there will always be a little leakage current from an amplifier's input. Don't forget the scope lead too - it might be a metre long and easily introduce 10 pF.

A 1 Mohm resistor might be enough to convert the leakage current to an offset of a few millivolts i.e. sufficiently small so as not to give a false measurement of any significance. So, with 1 Mohm and 1 nA leakage you get a millivolt offset change in the scope when you connect the probe tip and earth together. There is also the issue of noise - you would be unlikely to be impressed if the probe was unconnected and you saw 100 mVp-p of ripple on the display.

The 1 Mohm resistor and (say) 15 pF capacitor form a low pass circuit when the probe is unconnected and, subsequently have a noise bandwidth of about 15 kHz. Given that your scope analogue channel might have a noise of (say) 10 uV/\$\sqrt{Hz}\$, the ripple will be about 1 mV RMS or about 6 mVp-p (six sigma calculation). It's much more complex than this to analyse but hopefully, my simple calculation hints that there are other things to consider that might give the impression the scope's performance isn't that good when the probe is unconnected to a circuit.

Added to this is the need for all scopes to standardize between manufacturers means 1 Mohm is commonly accepted.

Answer (score 8):

In order to have a balanced 10:1 simple divider, the cable capacitance is tuned in the probe to match the cable capacitance which is lower than the standard 75 Ω coax and probably use 100  Ω (custom) coax, perhaps 10 pF/ft (33 pF/ft).

Each design of the scope preamplifier and coax feed has a different rating for capacitance, but a resistance of 1 MΩ is standard. Thus oscilloscope probes and oscilloscopes must be calibrated with a square wave test port on the front panel to give a square response. In better probes, there is also an inductive and two-stage RC balance.

[image]

[image]
[image]

However the ground lead inductance is not compensated, so for measurements with f > 10 MHz or rise times < 30 ns, the ground strap length must be reduced significantly or eliminated using tip and barrel between the two pins.

Answer (score 0):

One of our ADC designers just did a whole talk on oscilloscope front end design, you should check it out here:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzHyxysSubUmxGOMVpiKLxouweh2AAlG1

It went into a lot of the details about how the oscilloscope's front end and ADC work together.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance and capacitance in the probe form one section of a voltage divder, the resistance in the scope and combined capacitances in the cable and scope form the other section.   With a square wave source, the variable capacitor is adjusted to show a square wave on the scope.   With too much capacitance in the probe, you will see overshoot (pointy spiked corners) in the square wave display; with too little capacitance, you will see undershoot (rounded corners).  The goal of the system is to make the signal at the scope be representative of the signal you are probing.  This happens when the RC time constant of the probe is the same as the RC time constant of the cable+scope.

Of course, if you are probing a very high impedance source at high frequencies, you can expect trouble.   In that case, some kind of isolation amplifier would be required for you to see a true representation of your waveform.